# why do my xfire client post twices messages to the web server?

Tags: java, web-services, tcp

I create a webServices Project.then debug.and use xfire to export a client.i use the client to send message to my running webServices Project which blocked by a breakpoint.and after about five minutes .another message sent by the client which out of my expect.even i stop the client,it confuse me.our system should not accept the same message twices .anyone can help me ?thanks!

Comment: Whats this got to do with java :s

Comment: use java to write and deploy